# How would I translate, "Prosimus aliis potiti," and "in ordine?"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I'd appreciate it so much if someone would assess the accuracy of my translation of this Latin sentence, particularly the bolded sections:

Licet id fiat sine injuria alterius, & sine noxa valetudinis nostrae, dummodo id fiat nullo alio fine, quam ut nobis inde bene sit, **non autem ut istis potiti unquam aliis prosimus, nisi forte per accidens, & nostrae voluptatis aut utilitatis caussa**. Hac ratione mundum diligere vetat Apostolus, & Scriptores omnes sacri, quod **in ordine** ad divitias, honores, et voluptates, manifestum est.

Although this may be done without injury to another and without harm to our own health provided that it is done with no other end than that it may thence be well for us, but not that we may ever be benefited by being possessed with those other things, except perhaps by accident, and a cause of our pleasure or utility. In this way, the Apostle and all the Sacred Writers forbid loving the world, which is manifest in detail with regards to riches, honors, and pleasures.

Comment: ***Causa*** (final **a** long) with Genitive is usually: 'for the sake of...our pleasure etc.' giving the intent and motive.

Comment: Potiti is deponent participle, modifying the 'we' that is the subject of prosimus: 'having gained possession of' or 'having gained control over'; here, it takes an ablative object, istis, though it isn't really clear what this refers to. Also, the verb prosum means 'to benefit' or 'to be of use to', not 'to be benefitted by'; it takes a dative object, aliis.